# Display Name and Internal Name

Tags: development

I has this Code:

```
                    var query3 = new SPQuery();
                query3.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Dzien' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString() + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                SPListItemCollection poszczególnyDzien = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"].GetItems(query3);
                int sumaProcentow = 0;
                foreach (SPListItem oDzienSzczegolowy in poszczególnyDzien)
                {
                    int index;

                    index = oDzienSzczegolowy["Procenty"].ToString().IndexOf("#");
                    string procentKolejny = Convert.ToString(oDzienSzczegolowy["Procenty"]).Substring(index + 1,1);
```

Hoe to call on this field by Display Names, and Internal Names ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access the field the way you do in your sample, SharePoint will first try to look it up by internal name and, if that fails, will try to look it up by display name.

If you want to access it by internal name only, you do it like this:

```
SPField field = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"].Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Procenty");
foreach (SPListItem oDzienSzczegolowy in poszczególnyDzien)
{
    int index;

    index = oDzienSzczegolowy[field.Id].ToString().IndexOf("#");
    ...
```

Comment: And in CAML what schould I Write ? If i change name to the "Procenty22" It dont show me anything and throw null acception.

Comment: Use the Internal name for CAML; it should not change.